# Run PHP in Javascript function and create a confirm function with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql, sqlite

I have a function named `del()` that I want to use to delete a row in my SQL table. It is activated through a read cancel image onclick.

First I want it to output the following to the user:

```
"Are you sure you want to cancel your booking on". $row['Date'] .",". $row['Period'] . "," . $row['RoomID'] . "
```

But I don't know how to put it in the correct syntax nor if it will work as its within a javascript function.

Below is the function :

```
<script>
function del()
{
  var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel your booking on);
  if (r == true) {}
}
</script>
```

If `r == true` I want this SQL code to be executed.

```
<?php 
  DELETE FROM Booking WHERE BookingID='".$row['BookingID']."'";
?>
```

What would be the best way achieving this?

Comment: The best thing to do is to start using PDO with prepared/parameterized queries.  You are very likely open to SQL injection attacks the way your code works today.  You're probably also open to XSS attacks.

Comment: This is just a local project at home. Its running off my USB flashdrive. It wont ever see the light of day.

Comment: You need to send an HTTP request to the server to "run the PHP" - either a full FORM SUBMIT or AJAX. Search: "PHP AJAX".

Comment: just so you know, PHP knows **NOTHING** about sql. just because there's database interfaces for php, doesn't mean you can stuff some SQL into a php code block and expect a query to magically happen.

Comment: @user3568216 What's your point?  If you're not worried about security, worry about the fact that your application is effectively broken against apostrophes...  among other things.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed PHP variables in your JavaScript like this:

```
var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel your booking on <?php echo $row['Date']; ?>, <?php echo $row['Period']; ?>, <?php echo $row['RoomID']; ?>");
```

Submit your "delete request" using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX). Here's an example using the jQuery framework:

```
if (r)
{
    jQuery.post('url_to_your_script.php', { 'BookingId': '<?php echo $row['BookingId']; ?>' });
}
```

In your PHP script, you can refer to the booking ID as `$_POST['BookingId']`.

See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for information on more advanced parameters.

Comment: The embeded PHP variables did not work. Instead it only output " Are you sure you want to cancel your booking on , , "

Comment: So, you've made sure that they are set before, didn't you? It seems, the `$row` variable is the result of some database query. It would be helpful if you could provide more of your code on this, to help you.

Comment: Never inject arbitrary data directly into JavaScript.  Use `json_encode()` instead.  `{bookingId: <?php echo json_encode($row['BookingId); ?> }`